How to move a rigged up model in Blender (Human Hand)?
I'm new to the animating side of Blender, and have a hand model (pre-rigged) that I'm trying to bend into a peace sign shape. However, whenever I try to move the rigged bone portions, the hand becomes deformed and warped, and the hand doesn't bend properly.
If someone is able to bend this rigged up hand into a peace sign for me, I would be forever grateful.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/11ul8a3votkz8c4/Hand_Main.blend/file

This site is not for asking other people to do work for you. I strongly recommend you remove that aspect of your question. Meanwhile, I’ll try to look at your rig and see what’s wrong. You also generally want to attach a screenshot instead of just having people download a file before they can help. In turn, use blend-exchange.com to share your blend file on this site, whenever the size is small enough.

it seems to bend correctly, could you please be more specific, maybe show a picture?

Best I can tell, the rig is mostly normal, except that you've posed the bone thumb.003 when it should be zeroed, and "low-level" bones are visible when "high-level" control bones are present. To fix that:

In the 3D Viewport editor, select the armature.
Go into Pose Mode.
Press N to show the properties panel.
Hover over the quaternion rotations, and press backspace.
After that is done...
In the Properties editor, go to the Armature data-block tab.
In the Bone Collections panel, hide Layer 2 by clicking the eye next to it.

With only the control bones visible in Pose mode, all you have to do is select one and rotate it. The thumb control bone curls the thumb with its X rotation, while all the other finger control bones curl the fingers with their Z rotation.
For more information, see the blender manual page on armature posing.
